# Loading bitmap to ImageView using Async

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I am loading a bitmap asynchronous (ASyncTask) to the ImageView (its a background picture). The user can pick a custom background picture. When I start the application, I am loading the bitmap to the ImageView, but that takes some time (like 0.3 seconds). In this 0.3 seconds, I see the default background (black screen). I do like to see the custom background immediately.

How can I achieve this?

***EDIT***

With Glide I get exactly the same result, again a black screen for half a second.

If I use this code, without async, it works, but is good practise?

```
inputStream = new FileInputStream(createFile());
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

Comment: use glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Same result, seems like Glide uses also asyn to load the image.

Comment: This a normal behavior, because it takes time to decode. But a special background for waiting time

Comment: I would sugest loading a thumbnail version of the image and displaying it. It is better UX if the user at least sees a pixelized version of the image rather than a black screen.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Picasso Library

http://square.github.io/picasso/

It works like this :

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

With internal storage bitmap :

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(path)).into(imageView);
```

You can add an image that will be displayed during loading :

```
.placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_image))
```

Comment: I have a Bitmap, but it seems like I cannot use a bitmap as parameter in the load(). Any suggestions?

Comment: where is the bitmap ? Assets folder or drawable ?

Comment: I am loading it from internal memory. Glide supports it though, but it seems very slow to load.